# Adding extra UIlabel to each cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I'm trying to add an extra `UILabel` into each cell(`UITableView`)
I'v succeeded with this code in 
`(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

Here's my code

```
//add another text
UILabel *test = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250,80,50,20.0)];
test.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"test"];
test.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
test.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic" size:20];
[cell addSubview:test];
```

However I figured that if I do this, I can't add different text to each cell, instead, it ends up with the same text in all cells. Can anyone tell me how to do that?
Oh and another problem was that if I do this, "test" is displayed in every cell except for the first one.

Comment: can you paste your cellForRowAtIndexPath fully ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the tutorial "[UITableView – Adding subviews to a cell’s content view](https://xcode4all.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/uitableview-%E2%80%93-adding-subviews-to-a-cell%E2%80%99s-content-view/)".

Try something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {

    CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 65);
    CGRect Label1Frame = CGRectMake(17,5,250,18);  

    UILabel *lblTemp;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];  
    lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label1Frame];
    [lblTemp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:15]];
    lblTemp.tag = 1;
    lblTemp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lblTemp.numberOfLines=0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];      
    return cell;  // this I forgot  
}
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
{
    if(cell == nil)
            cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];  
    lblTemp1.text =[nameArray objectAtIndex:value+indexPath.row];  
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: hey, i get this "control reaches end of non-void function" warning message from the getCellContentView method :(

Comment: This is a bit outdated now. It says it was depreciated in iOS 3, and we're up to 8 now.

Answer (score 2):

For having the same Label on all cells, you are probably instantiating just one cell and use the `cellReUseIdentifier` for all cells. So, I suggest that you create different labels as properties of the class, and assign each `property-label` to each cell.

```
// For example - 

if (indexPath.row ==0 )
  // assign [cell.contentView addSubview: self.label1];

if (indexPath.row ==1 )
  // assign [cell.contentView addSubview: self.label2];
```

And for the second part of the question, please post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` fully - there could be an error in that.

Answer (score 2):

First check if any of the predefined styles work for you.

If you need more flexibility than what they offer, you can try something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [self makeCell: CellIdentifier];
    }

    MyData *data =  [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    lbl1.text = data.text;
    lbl2.text = data.auxText;    

    return cell;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)makeLensListCell: (NSString *)identifier
{
    CGRect lbl1Frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 140, 25);
    CGRect lbl2Frame = CGRectMake(10, 150, 140, 25);

    UILabel *lbl;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

    // Label with tag 1.
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lbl1Frame];
    lbl.tag = 1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl release];

    // Label with tag 2.
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lbl2Frame];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl release];

    // Add as many labels and other views as you like

    return cell;
}
```

This approach also allows images and other views.